# Is there a way to adjust the style of the input of type file ..,?

Tags: html, css, button, attributes

Okay .. I want to create a button once it's clicked it allows you to add a photo .. like the input tag of attribute type = "file" .. I've already designed the button shape .. all what is remained is to click on it so a window blows up .. and choose a photo to display in the post box ..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJ1oE.png)

```html
                                <div class="extras">
                                    <ul class="icons">
                                        <li class="photos"> 
                                            <i class="fa-solid fa-image">
                                            </i>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="tag"> <i class="fa-solid fa-user-tag"> </i> </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <div class="button">
                                        <button>launch</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

here is the element of class photos which I want it to display the window of adding a photo once it's clicked .. exactly like  .. just different button style ..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, what you have to do is this: first you'll need to add an id to your `<li class="photos">` and your `<button>launch</button>`. And also remove your `<i id="up">` component since you'll add it with JavaScript. See the html bellow.

```
<div class="extras">
  <ul class="icons">
    <li id="photos-component" class="photos"> 
      <!-- there used to be an  <i> tag here! -->
    </li>
    <li class="tag">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-user-tag"> </i>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="button">
    <button id="launch-button">launch</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

After adding the ids, you'll need to call a JavaScript file by inserting a `<script src="insert-your-file-name.js"></script>` at the bottom of your `<body>`. Probably, you already have done this. If not, do it.

In that file, you'll want to add the following code.

```
// This constant bellow contains your photos component
const photosComponent = document.getElementById("photos-component");

// This constant bellow contains your launch button
const button = document.getElementById("launch-button");

// This whole chunk of code bellow is a function that will run whenever
// you click the button
button.addEventListener("click", () => {

  // Here we create a new empty <input> tag 
  const fileInput = document.createElement("input");

  // Here we add all the attributes for the <input> tag
  fileInput.id = "up";
  fileInput.type = "file";
  fileInput.classList.add("fa-solid fa-image");

  // Here we add the input to the photos component
  photosComponent.append(fileInput);

  // Here we change the style of the button
  button.classList.add("insert-button-style");

})
```

Hopefully it helps. You can always read more about the JavaScript HTML DOM (Document Object Model) by googleing it.

These links might help you in your search:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp

https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/

Comment: I'm sorry it seemed to be my fault of wrong description ..

Comment: The launch button has nothing to do with my intentions ..

Comment: I've added an image .. which will be showing more details ..

Comment: However your code gave me a blurred idea .. which I need to think more to get it clarified ..